# How to scroll to component position?

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, components

I want to scroll to the component position in Angular. Components are generated according to repeticiones var. This is my HTML code.[image: HMTL code]

And this is the TS code:[image: TS code]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use id and viewportScroller instead of elem

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <button (click)="onAnchorScroll(1)"></button>
    ...
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of repecticiones; let i = index" [id]="i + 1">
    ...
</div>
```

**TS**

in your ts import ViewportScroller from @angular/common

```
constructor(private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) { }

onAnchorScroll(id) {
  this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(id);
}
```